# crossvalidation metrics in pyspark.ml

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am building the cross-validation model on the dataset. The cross-validation object has **avgMetrics** attributes which are returning an array.

```
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol='label',predictionCol='prediction',metricName='f1')

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=self.pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=evaluator,
                          numFolds=2)
print(cvModel.avgMetrics)
[0.42175585108783414,
 0.4585199817620358,
 0.39932871646955814,
 0.4310619715036083,
 0.46251606720905303,
 0.42030120869345633,
 0.41120037704551726,
 0.4650393846493733,
 0.3478141848099525]
```

The **cvMode.avgMetrics** returning an array of metrics. How do I get to know what metrics it is returning? Is there anyway to get the name of the metrics?

Answer (score 0):

It is [F1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) . You chose it when constructing `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`